# How to work with velocity context variable as local variable

Tags: java, velocity

In velocity i have a problem. Let me explain clearly as below
     I have declared in class

```
private final static int MAX_TOOL_TITLE_LENGTH = 20;

//Putting into context
context.put("maxToolTitleLength","MAX_TOOL_TITLE_LENGTH");
```

Now in vm file i am setting the context variable value as different

```
#if(true)
  #set($maxToolTitleLength=99) 
#end
```

In the above lines in vm file i set value as 99.i do not want to set this value to context  variable.i want to limit the scope of the variable with in the if only. After if i don't want to get the value as 99.it remains same value as in the context. Is it possible in velocity in any of other ways?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, velocity has no scoped blocks.

Comment: Then how to get out of problem.if i change the context variable value in template file.it doesn't effect the context variable?

Comment: It may be possible to provide a solution if you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: IN my project there is a text length validation.i have a four text boxes.for three text boxes i want to allow 20 characters.For other one i required 90 characters to allow.before developers developed that,they take one variable in the context and set value to 20.in velocity template they give the this variable as max length attribute value.if i change the value in template file,it is applying to all text boxes because it is context variable.so how to give a 90 to that particular text box?

Answer (score 4):

There *is* actually a way to introduce local variables in Velocity, though it is a bit surprising:

```
#foreach ($maxToolTitleLength in [99])
...text that uses this $maxToolTitleLength definition...
#end
## now $maxToolTitleLength is back to whatever value it had before
```

`[99]` is a list with one element, `99`, so this is a loop that executes one time. Within the loop `$maxToolTitleLength` has the value `99`. You can also `#set ($maxToolTitleLength = $anotherValue)` within the loop. The value from before the `#foreach` will be restored after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The #foreach-hack, as found by @user2624542, works to generate local scopes. However, at least in the quite old Velocity 1.5 of Polarion the behavior inside a macro is different than outside.

**Inside macros the scoping works for existing variables (in the global context), but not for undefined ones.**

```
$foo ## undef
#foreach ($foo in [99])
  $foo ## 99
  #set($foo=100)
  $foo ## 100
#end
$foo ## undef

#set($foo=0)
$foo ## 0
#foreach ($foo in [99])
  $foo ## 99
  #set($foo=100)
  $foo ## 100
#end
$foo ## 0
```

whereas inside a macro

```
#macro(bar)
  $foo ## undef
  #foreach ($foo in [99])
    $foo ## 99
    #set($foo=100)
    $foo ## 100
  #end
  $foo ## 100 NOT undef
#end

$foo ## undef
#bar()
$foo ## 100 NOT undef

#macro(bar2)
  $foo ## 0
  #foreach ($foo in [99])
    $foo ## 99
    #set($foo=100)
    $foo ## 100
  #end
  $foo ## 0
#end

#set($foo=0)
$foo ## 0
#bar2()
$foo ## 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the value of a context object and make this change local only. I don't see why you don't simply use a new variable in your template for this?

```
#if (true)
  #set($thisTitleLength=99) 
#end
```

Or if you do need to use the context variable for this, just restore the context variable after you finish the block where you want to change its value:

```
#if (true)
  #set($maxToolTitleLength=99) 
  ## Do whatever you want with the new value
  ...
  ## Now restore its value
  #set($maxToolTitleLength=20)
#end
```